# How can I merge drop-down columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

Please see [Investment Portfolio Tracker - TMOAP Official Version 5.2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jXw_ggLEwTiIrr9C80ZReM4Z3ADe0sS7DxLWaPHGtUg/edit#gid=1249014201).

If the three columns (in red rectangles) remain the same for rows 5-20, it's obviously foolish and unproductive to click on the drop-down menu and pick the same three specifics (VA, Buy, RRSP)   48 (16 x 3) times.

Thus how can I be more productive, and click on the drop-down menu and pick merely 3 times (once for each of the three columns)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it individually for each cell, you are able to apply it to the whole range at once by adding **`:C`** at the end like:

[image: 0]

---

To override multiple cells in the range you are able to reference the start point and then manage the whole area just from one cell. For example, if you paste **`=C$5`** into **C6** cell and drag down to reach **C15** then you are able to influence **C6:C15** directly  from **C5** cell:

[image: 0]

Comment: Suppose that C6-C15 are for stock purchases. Then "Cell range" is `Trade Log`!C6:C15. I just tried this, but this Cell Range doesn't cause the drop-down menus to select 'Buy' automatically? Can you please add more detail to the post?

Comment: @TamaraM. answer updated